# Include not working as expected

Tags: php

This has me pretty baffled, so I have a simple include line in my php but it for some reason does not always work right.

Basically the include is loading my main content section...

if `$page['view']` is `list` my page will not load correctly...

the php I have is

```
include ('lib/views/' . $page['view'] . '.php');
```

However the page does not load and nothing below this point loads including the footer...

This works as expected

```
echo 'lib/views/' . $page['view'] . '.php';
```

My apache2 error log spits out the following error

```
include(): Failed opening 'lib/views/.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/site/www/lib/includes/main.php on line 3
```

When I try this, the footer reappears but still same error

```
$view = 'lib/views/' . $page['view'] . '.php';
include ($view);
```

This is pretty baffling to me, especiall considering that if `$page['view']` is `avatar` it then works

**EDIT 1**

As suggested by @philwc I have added this to my code

```
if (isset($page['view'])) {
        var_dump($page['view']);
}
```

Which outputs as expected `list`

Comment: Do you have any URL rewrite rules that it could be triggering?

Comment: I initially thought that may be the reason as well, however I have since turned RewriteEngine Off and still the problem persists

Comment: Curious, what happens if you try `include ("lib/views/{$page['view']}.php");`

Comment: Ah, ok so I got it, @Darren that helped, it then spit out a different error, I had an error on the 'list.php' page and was not getting that error for some reason, when I tried your code I then got the correct error code that helped me fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
include ("lib/views/{$page['view']}.php");
```

As you stated it will give you a different error, just mark this correct so that it doesn't sit in limbo :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $page['view'] is not set correctly. Try wrapping it with an isset like

```
if(isset($page['view'])){
    include ('lib/views/' . $page['view'] . '.php');
}else{
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

Comment: Tried that, I updated my question to accommodate your answer though

Comment: I'm assuming that list.php exists within the lib/views folder?

Comment: It might also be worth checking your php include path - php can do some funny things sometimes...

Comment: That is correct, but as you can see in the error it is looking for `lib/views/.php` and ignoring the `page['view']` variable

Comment: I used an absolute path as well and that did not work

Comment: You can also try setting an absolute path with something like `__DIR__.'/lib/views/'.$page['view'].'.php'`

Comment: What's the result of `$view = 'lib/views/' . $page['view'] . '.php'; var_dump($view);`?